# Choose the index of value in array greater than zero and

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two np arrays (A, B). Some of the values in A are 0.

I want to choose the value in A greater than zero.

And choose the indices in B.

And finally, save the values in a dictionary (I don't know that it is possible or not).

Here are the A and B and the dic which I want.

```
import numpy as np
A = [[20, 30, 40, 50], [0, 4, 0, 0], [1, 2, 4,0]]
B = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 14, 7, 10], [7, 1, 3,20] ]

dic = ['1': [20, 30, 40, 50], [1, 2, 3, 4],'2': [ 4], [ 14],'3':[1, 2, 4], [7, 1, 3] ] #which I want
```

Can anybody help me to solve this? Thank you so much

Comment: It's unclear which problem you were facing while doing this.

Comment: You haven't really shown what you've attempted or researched, you just showed what you want and are basically asking us to do it all for you. More effort is required I'd say. This has more info on what is expected: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/6273251)

Comment: I don't know how to choose the index of the value greater than zero in A and then create a dic that includes that index from A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do that. Something like below:

```
A = [[20, 30, 40, 50], [0, 4, 0, 0], [1, 2, 4, 0]]
B = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 14, 7, 10], [7, 1, 3, 20]]

result_dict = {}
for index, item in enumerate(A):
    result_dict[index] = [[elem for elem in A[index] if elem>0], [elem for elem in B[index] if elem>0]]

print(result_dict)
# OUTPUT
# {0: [[20, 30, 40, 50], [1, 2, 3, 4]], 1: [[4], [5, 14, 7, 10]], 2: [[1, 2, 4], [7, 1, 3, 20]]}
```

I understand sometimes it's difficult to understand how to proceed when you are new.
Please learn the basics of the language you are using prior to using modules like np.
For example you can easily iterate over a list and use index to do this using basic python rules.

I've used enumerate(), and list comprehension for this example, you can use other methods as well!

Happy coding :)